# Implementing SCD type2 in Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-groups, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Am trying to implement type2 in Datafusion.Can someone help in performing insert and updating by using the pipeline transformations/action/conditions to achieve this. I was trying to generate hash using Wrangler for both source and Target and join them. I was struck here ,not sure how to determine which goes to update/insert and how to handle those.My Target is BigQuery tables.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack overflow @Manasa!

Once you are considering [Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-pl-all-en-dr-skws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1008073&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_167401602652-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20~%20EXA_1:1_PL_EN_Data_BigQuery_TOP_bigquery-KWID_43700016291537629-kwd-47616965283-userloc_9067437&utm_term=KW_bigquery-ST_bigquery&ds_rl=1242850&ds_rl=1245734&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgMqHmaHY5wIVBp53Ch1Zjg7CEAAYASAAEgJfsPD_BwE) as a warehouse for the target sink, leveraging [*SCD type2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row) merging method, you might have first to get the practice way how to implement it composing particular SQL statement, reaching the desired logic. Saying this, I encourage you to study [this](https://medium.com/happiestneurons/slowly-changing-dimension-type-2-scd2-in-big-query-95330ce31625) great article written by [@Hariharan Ramachandran](https://medium.com/@haran.ramachandran), explaining `SCD` techniques with some hand on examples using Bigquery service as a destination data holder.

According to [Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/) documentation, you can find a rich set of [Plugins](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview#plugin), extending standard data processing workflows.Therefore, in this particular case I would recommend implementing `BigQuery Execute` plugin which can be adjusted in your pipeline, executing SQL queries against Bigquery managed service and perform some `SCD2` specific actions.

[image]